# Android - is JSON a good choice for storing size varying data in an unchanging SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, parsing

I have various Exercise objects containing ArrayLists of as many Set objects as the user wants.

I was planning to store these objects in an SQLite database and I was thinking JSON seems like a good choice as I can store as much data as I want in the JSONObject, store it indefinitely and then retreive it whenever.

Is this a sensible way to go about storing dynamic object data in an organized database for an indefinite amount of time?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that is a sensible way..Furthermore, storing JSON in the database is in general a very safe approach. If also you care about the parsing speed try to use the Jackson Library instead of the org.json because the first is a few times faster than the second.